# Can't get the login routes to work in Symfony 2

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony

I have tried all the configs on every manual, and still can't get it to work!
Can someone help me find the error please? Here's my code:

**Security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        users:
            user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
            admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: in_memory
        anonymous: true
        security: true
        form_login:
            login_path: default_login
            check_path: default_check
        logout:
            path: default_logout
            target: default_index
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 3600
            domain: ~
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/afiliados, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN}
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
namespace Epika\ClubBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

/**
 * Default controller.
 *
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="default_login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
                $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="default_check")
     * 
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
        //Security Layer
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="default_logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        //Security Layer
    }

}
```

In my form I have

```
<form name="loginForm" action="{{ path('default_check') }}" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="_username" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" />
<input type="password" name="_password" placeholder="Tú Contraseña" />
<input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me" />
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/index" />
<a href="javascript:submit()"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/epikaclub/images/entrar.png') }}" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{
    document.loginForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

OK Guys Thank you very much for all the help, The problem was that the login form enctype was set to

```
<form name="loginForm" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

which was causing the request to be empty :S sorry, once I set it to

```
<form name="loginForm" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

It worked fine, now I have to check it with the Doctrine Entity Provider and see how it goes :D

Comment: Thanks to the debug I found out that the redirect to login_check happens with the data I provide in the login form, but somehow the session does not get modified nor stored, what can I do ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to:

- Use the actual URL (like others said here, i.e. '/login_check')
- Do not make a controller for the login_check route. I don't think the route itself is even necessary. Symfony2 will see the request for '/login_check' and intercept it automatically.

It's explained in one of the sidenotes here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

The 'bad credentials' error, even when putting in the right information, just points to some error happening somewhere. Check the error logs if it still doesn't work with what I mentioned above and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to tweak your login_path and check_path values to be an actual URL path, like so:

```
firewalls:
    [...]
    main:
        [...]
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
```

Sam

Comment: I did it, and I get the bad credentials message all the time, however when I use the routes names I get an Exception saying the login_check route doesn't match the firewall's pattern :S, so I'm a bit confused >_>

Comment: Using the URLs is the right way - the error might just be something in your session that needs to be cleared out? Do you still get the error even after successfully logging in & then logging out?

Comment: I never get to login successfully it just sends me back to the login page with the bad credentials message all the time even if I use a good combination

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other options, `check_path` doesn't support route names. Set it to a path like `/login_check`.

Comment: I dit it, and nothing I keep getting back to the login page with the bad credentials message, could it be something wrong in the session ? do I need to configure something else ?